# Rhomobile vs. MoSync/Phonegap/HTML5

Tags: android, ios, cordova, rhomobile

I am interested in supporting a few different platforms, like Android, iOS, Windows, and I was interested in Rhomobile might help?  However, I am concerned about not being able to use any device specific syncing capabilities.   Has anyone worked with PhoneGap/MoSync combo and what has been your experience?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "not being able to use any device specific syncing capabilities" with Rhomobile. You can always create your own syncing mechanism using the network libraries as described here: 
[Connecting Directly with Web Services](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/connect-to-web-services)

You can also create native extensions and use them inside your Rhodes project so no native capability is impossible to access. Of course you would have to replicate this extension for every platform you are targetting or manage the differences in implementation in your code in a platform specific way.

Regarding the comparisson with the other multi-platform frameworks, we evaluated using PhoneGap but ended up deciding for Rhodes because of the development tools. Having a development tool that has integrated step-by-step debugging and the Rhodes simulator that allows you to test and manipulate your style sheets and works 100 times faster than the android emulator is a major advantage.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, makes me feel a bit more confident about rhomobile.